# Identifying calling convention from .pdb file

Tags: symbols, debug-symbols, disassembly, ida, pdb-files

I'm interested in a symbol from `.pdb` file, which I want to programmatically identify its calling conventions - it might be either `fastcall` or `stdcall` in different versions of a certain dll.

I see that `IDA Pro` and similar disassemblers know how to specify it in the right way.

Is there any way that I can identify it from my code?